# URI vs URL in React Native

Tags: url, react-native, uri, webaddress

In react-native one can do:

```
const somePath = 'https://...'
<Image source={somePath} />
```

or

```
const somePath = 'https://...'
<Image source={{uri: somePath}} />
```

From what I understand about web addresses is that URIs are a superset of URLs and URNs.

**Questions**

1. What are the potential problems associated with supplying a web address to `source` as a URL?
2. What are the potential problems associated with supplying a web address to `source` as a URI?
3. Which method of supplying an address of an image to `source` is more accurate, safer, and future proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first code example you provided won't work

```
const somePath = 'https://...'
<Image source={somePath} />
```

In general general you should use the source prop to provide a local image like so

```
const someLocalImage = require("./assets/someImageName.png");
<Image source={someLocalImage} />
```

and the uri to display a remote image like so

```
<Image source={{uri: "https://example.com/someRemoteImagePath.png" />
```

You can also use the uri to display base64 image data

```
<Image
      source={{uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='}}
    />
```

Read more about it in the documentation

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#source