# React-native unidentified is not an object

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

When I dispatch my delete action to Redux I am getting the error `unidentified is not an object evaluating selectedUser.imageUri` Everything is being loaded from a server and I know the delete action works as it deletes the object from the server however I get this error and the screen only updates when I reload the application. Please can someone help me I really need your help. Thank you so much in advance!!!I am even checking to see if there is no object in the `selecetedUser` array then render an image called `nothing.png`

This is my code where I am seeing the error

```
const Viewer = (props) => {
    const userID = props.navigation.getParam('id')
    //Nothing is just a picture when there are no images
    import nothing from './Images/nothing.png'

    const selectedUser = useSelector(state => state.user.user.find(user => user.id === userID))
    const cBimageUri = {uri: selectedUser.imageUri }
    const checkImage = cBimageUri.length === 0? nothing : cBimageUri
    const cBimageUri = {uri: selectedUser.imageUri }

    const deleteCb = useCallback(() =>{
        dispatch(deleteUser(userID))
        props.navigation.goBack()
    },[userID])

    useEffect(() => { 
        props.navigation.setParams({deleteCb: deleteCb})
    },[deleteCb])

    return (
        <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
            <Image source={checkImage} style={styles.image}/>
            <Text style={styles.name}>{selectedCookBook.name}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

export default Viewer
```

Redux reducer

```
import { CREATE_USER, DELETE_USER } from '../actions/account'

const initialState = {
    account: [],
}

const USerReducer = (state=initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){

        case CREATE_USER:
            const newUser = new MyUser(
                action.userData.id,
                action.userData.name,
                action.userData.image, 
            )
            
            return { ...state, user: state.account.concat(newUser)}

        case DELETE_USER:
            const filteredItems = state.account.filter(cb => cb.id !== action.deleteCb)
            return {account: filteredItems }
 
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
export default USerReducer
```

Redux action

```
export const DELETE_COOKBOOK = 'CLEAR'
export const deleteCookbook = (deleteCb) => {
    return {type: DELETE_COOKBOOK, deleteCb: deleteCb}
}
```

console logging selectedUser

```
[
    Object {
          "id": 1595444079901,
          "val": "Veveve",
    },

    name: John Snow,
    imageUri: 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Frn-first-app-e648c632-2715-4169-abf3-e0cdbe2ac7d5/ImagePicker/461b63af-a908-47e9-8841-d5d8f2c4eb67.jpg
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Frn-first-app-e648c632-2715-4169-abf3-e0cdbe2ac7d5/ImagePicker/461b63af-a908-47e9-8841-d5d8f2c4eb67.jpg'
}
]
```

Comment: could you post more code? Because it's not clear what is selectedUser.imageUri

Comment: I could but selected user is just an array of objects in my redux-store rendering an 'id', "image", and "details" in each array

Comment: I've added the additional code to make it clearer. I really hope you can help me

Comment: still ... could you do console.log(selectedUser)?

Comment: Thank you for your help so far . I have provided the console log. The image.uri is a location from my local database using async storage with redux-persist.

Comment: Maybe you should change it ->const cBimageUri = {uri: selectedUser.image}

Comment: NO because imageUri is the variable name

Answer (score 0):

Try to change follow

```
const Viewer = (props) => {
    const userID = props.navigation.getParam('id')
    //Nothing is just a picture when there are no images
    import nothing from './Images/nothing.png'

    const selectedUser = useSelector(state => state.user.user.find(user => user.id === userID))
    const cBimageUri = selectedUser.imageUri // --> changed it
    const checkImage = cBimageUri.length === 0? nothing : cBimageUri
    //const cBimageUri = {uri: selectedUser.imageUri } // is it a right row? just repeat previous 

    const deleteCb = useCallback(() =>{
        dispatch(deleteUser(userID))
        props.navigation.goBack()
    },[userID])

    useEffect(() => { 
        props.navigation.setParams({deleteCb: deleteCb})
    },[deleteCb])

    return (
        <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
            <Image source={{uri: checkImage}} style={styles.image}/> // --> changed it. Not sure about it, if it's not working check below link
            <Text style={styles.name}>{selectedCookBook.name}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

export default Viewer
```

this link  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249353/uri-vs-url-in-react-native](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249353/uri-vs-url-in-react-native)